# How do I prove the following: $f(S\cup T) = f(S) \cup f(T)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

I have a question.

How do I prove the following identity?
$$ 
f(S\cup T) = f(S) \cup f(T)
$$

Comment: Prove both inclusions. Go step by step. If $y$ belongs to the lhs, there is $x$ in $S\cup T$ such that $y= f(x)$. If $x$ belongs to $S$ in the first place, then $y=f(x)$ belongs to $f(S)\subseteq f(S)\cup f(T)$. Etc...

Comment: it's not clear. Are you saying that given two sets s and t, the set of values of f on the union of s and t is the same as the union of the set of values of f(s) and f(t)?

Comment: 1. please use latex for math notation. 2. what are your own thoughts? what is your definition of them being equal?

Comment: Please notice for further reference the $\LaTeX$ editing that has been made to your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Element chasing is a promising method here.

$y\in f(s\cup t)$ if and only if there is some $x\in s\cup t$ such that $f(x)=y$. If $x\in s$ then $y\in f(s)$, if $x\in t$ then $y\in f(t)$. Therefore $y\in f(s)\cup f(t)$.

I leave the second inclusion to you.

Comment: Apparently something is wrong in the argument above?

Answer (score 2):

You know that if $R$ is a relation an d $A$ is a set then $$R(A)=\{y\mid\exists x(x\in A\wedge xRy)\}$$ now try to show that $$R(A\cup B)=R(A)\cup R(B)$$

Answer (score 1):

You don't prove a function, but an identity which states that 
$$f(S \cup T) = f(S) \cup f(T)$$
When $x\in f(S\cup T)$ it means there is a $y \in S \cup T$ such that $f(y)=x$ make the same on the right hand side and compare both.

Comment: thanks first wanted to write $y\in S \vee y \in T$ but then i messed up

Comment: Hi Dominic. I've noticed you often use the verb "to proof". [It exists](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/proof), but it does not mean "to prove". So I thought I'd let you know. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @julien oh thanks i hope i won't forget it

Comment: @julien: Perhaps Dominic was pointing out that we are proofing the proof against mistakes? :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila He, he! That was funny. And indeed a possibility. Although it's been ruled out by Dominic's comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Begin your argument as follows.  Can you move it further?
$$
y\in f(s\cup t) \iff \exists x\in s\cup t \hbox{s.t.} f(x) = y 
$$